# Can you launch a telnet window from Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I currently have a link that launches a telnet link like this

```
<h:outputLink value="telnet://1.2.3.4">
    <h:outputText value="1.2.3.4" />
</h:outputLink>
```

All the users have their browsers configured correctly to launch some telnet client or other when they click this link.

I want to change the link, which currently appears on the page, to a link in a context menu (`rich:menuItem`).

Menu items apparently do not play well with JSF outputLinks (or any other kind of links). You need to implement it as the value of an `onclick` event:

```
<rich:menuItem value="View Details" onclick="window.location='http://ond.ba.ssa.gov" />
```

I tried implement the telnet this same way:

```
<rich:menuItem value="1.2.3.4" onclick="window.location='telnet://1.2.3.4'" />
```

But it doesn't work. Should it? Is there a simple way to do this?  If so, I haven't been able to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should describe in what way this "doesn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC older IEs have some kind of exec method you could invoke/exploit, but almost everything else will treat this as a security violation.

Comment: "All the users have their browsers configured correctly" implies that all necessary security options were set.

Comment: @jAndy - this is nothing to do with security configuration so much as browser sandboxing. Put it this way, if it was a matter of configuration then it would work.

Comment: Actually I suppose if you wanted to limit to IE, it *might* be possible through new ActiveXObject(foo) - not tried that, and would be a little shocked if it did work.

Comment: Too bad. I'm just going to ditch the idea of putting this in the menu item.  Thanks for the feedback.